# How to turn off tape (mt-st) compression on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tape

A recent upgrade from 14.04 to 18.04 on a host with with a LTO-6 tape drive shows the `mt` command no longer supports the `compression` argument.  Anyone know another way to toggle drive compression?

```
# mt /dev/nst0 compression off                                                                                                                                                          
mt: invalid argument ‘/dev/nst0’ for ‘operation’
Valid arguments are:
  - ‘eof’, ‘weof’
  - ‘fsf’
  - ‘bsf’
  - ‘fsr’
  - ‘bsr’
  - ‘rewind’
  - ‘offline’, ‘rewoffl’, ‘eject’
  - ‘status’
  - ‘bsfm’
  - ‘eom’
  - ‘retension’
  - ‘erase’
  - ‘asf’
  - ‘fsfm’
  - ‘seek’
```

Comment: It looks to me like it's complaining about your block device argument - are you sure that shouldn't be `mt -f /dev/nst0 compression off` ?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Should be a `-f device` in there. Missed that. Even with it, however, the `compression` command fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else running across this, looks like the `mt` package installed is the `mt-gnu` package. I had to install the `mt-st` package to get the compression command.

Comment: https://github.com/iustin/mt-st this is the upstream source for the reader, who got here.